# How to consider only first two elements from *pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

From the below code you can see that the vector array has the same number twice or more than. What I want to do is to find the first two same number's  position from the pointer *ptr

```
 #include<iostream> 
#include<iterator> // for iterators 
#include<vector> // for vectors 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> ar = { 1,8,2, 2, 2, 5,7,7,7,7,8 }; 

    // Declaring iterator to a vector 
    vector<int>::iterator ptr; 

    // Displaying vector elements using begin() and end() 
    cout << "The vector elements are : "; 
    for (ptr = ar.begin(); ptr < ar.end(); ptr++) 
        cout << *ptr << " "; 
        return 0;     
}
```

Let's assume I want to print out the first two position and elements of 7 by dereferencing the pointer *ptr. Should I use an if a condition like

```
int *array = ptr.data(); 
for( int i =0; i < ar.size(); i++) {

if( array[i] - array[i+1]+ ==0)
    cout<<array[i]<<endl;
```

}

But how would I guarantee that it is not looking for the only first two same elements from *ptr?

**UPDATE**

Clearing the question:

1. The reason I always want to know the first and second position of the same element from the dereferencing the pointer is that later I will do some study, and in that study, I will be given some time associated with the first and second position of the same number. The problem, I wanted to ignore the same elements which are still repetitive after the second time is because I want to ignore these element positions in my calculations.
2. For example, if you print out the code you would find the element: **The vector elements are 1 8 2 2 2 5 7 7 7 7 8 **. In this case, the first two positions of the element 2, is [2], and [3], therefore I would like to ignore the position [4].  Another thing to mention, that I don't care if the value or consequent or not[I mean for example 828, or 888, I would consider both]. For example, the number 8 is in location array[1], and in the [10]. I would also consider this.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit more?

Comment: I have updated the question Rietty

Comment: Are you interested just in consequent repeating values (like [2 2 2])? From your comments I assume that only consequent repeating values should be reported (so in this example the second occurrence of 2 should not be reported [2  8 2]).  What if the same value is repeated more than once in the vector (like in [2 2 8 2 2])?

Comment: That's a good point, Martin. I have updated the question.  The number doesn't have to be consequent. The only thing I care if the number is repetitive in the array, and find the first two positions of the same number.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but still important: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` or `unordered_map` to register indexes of each value.

Here's a simple demo of the concept:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> ar{ 1, 8, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 };
  map<int, vector<size_t> > occurrences{ };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i) {
    occurrences[ar[i]].push_back(i);
  }

  for (const auto& occurrence:occurrences) {
    cout << occurrence.first << ": ";
    for (auto index: occurrence.second) {
      cout << index << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1: 0
2: 2 3 4
5: 5
7: 6 7 8 9
8: 1 10
```

Comment: Let's assume I want to print out the second position of the number 2, which should be 2.

How to do that?

Comment: @zero_field `cout << occurrences[2][1] << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

Create a map where each value is stored as key, mapped to a list of indices:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<size_t>> indexMap;
```

Loop over your initial values and fill the map:

```
for (size_t index = 0; index < ar.size(); index++)
{
    indexMap[ar[index]].push_back(index);
}
```

Now you can loop over your map and work with every value that has 2 or more indices and only use the first 2 indices for whatever you want to do:

```
for (auto const& [value, indices] : indexMap)
{
    if (indices.size() < 2)
        continue;

    size_t firstIndex = indices[0];
    size_t secondIndex = indices[1];

    // do whatever
}
```

*(If you don't use C++17 or up, use `for (auto const& pair : indexMap)`, where `pair.first` is `value` and `pair.second` is `indices`.)*

Comment: I understand the logic, except what I should use in the initial value? Here:  

`indexMap[value].push_back(index);`